# API Gateway as DynamoDB non-proxy integration with Integration Response for variable Map returns

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway, vtl

Given an AWS Service integration (DynamoDB) in API Gateway, I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically parse DynamoDB-structured JSON and return it in standard JSON format **WITHOUT** a standalone Lambda function mapper? For easier demonstration, here's an example of two possible data elements existing in my DynamoDB table I'd like to return in standard JSON format using a single Integration Response mapping template, if possible:

Ex. 1

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "desc": "here's a string type at depth 1",
    "info": {
        "key1": "a string at depth 2"
    }
}
```

Ex. 2

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "desc": "here's a string type at depth 1",
    "info": {
        "key1": "a string at depth 2"
        "key2": {
            "subkey1": "look, a string at depth 3"
        }
    }
}
```

Based on these two examples, we can see these are nested data structures that share top-level keys, but have a variable number of nested tiers.

I've noted the following in all of the answers to questions regarding Integration Mapping Templates **WITHOUT** using a separate Lambda function to resolve the mapping:

1. Parsing Integration Response mapping templates for "flat" DynamoDB data -- e.g. something like this, where there's effectively a data depth of 1 since all elements in the data are basic types like `S` or `N`:

```
{
    "param1": "some stuff",
    "param2": "other stuff"
}
```

2. Any answers dealing with more complex data  types like `M` presume the question writer knows without a doubt exactly what the DynamoDB table elements look like. So, they'll say something like 'create the mapping template for each of the layers with the appropriate, expected return type for that field.' Using Ex. 1 to illustrate a solution Integration Response mapping template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "id": "$input.Item.id.S",
    "desc": "$input.Item.desc.S",
    "info": {
        "key1": "$input.Item.info.M.key1.S"
    }
}
```

Now, this works if we actually know what the expected DynamoDB result fields will be for every depth and how many tiers each table element has -- i.e., the data in a NoSQL table should be structured? Barring there being some version of the AppSync VTL resolver `$util.dynamodb.toJSON` method that can effectively unwrap dynamically-shaped DynamoDB returns, is there a way to do this directly without having to utilize a standalone Lambda function? Is there a way to generalize the response mapping template to account for variably-nested `M` type data?

One idea I've had is to loop through all of the keys and sending the `M` types to a secondary loop, but this seems impractical given:

1. the number of iterations that could theoretically be required to unwrap a deeply-nested object (DynamoDB can support up to 32 layers, last I checked), and
2. the variability in the nesting from element to element in the table.

To point 1, `#foreach` has a hard limit on the number of iterations it's capped at: 1000 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=225222

I'm dubious as to the prospect of a non-Lambda solution, but still curious. Thoughts?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's going to be doable without AWS adding some sort of util function to help. Anything that you might come up with, if it's even possible, would likely be way more complex than a lambda solution.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth I was sort of thinking that, but still curious. I've started experimenting with two separate approaches (each with their drawbacks):
1. creating a `Model` type in API Gateway and then having the Integration Response enforce the type -- still somewhat inflexible, but a solution if I want to avoid a Lambda call or
2. having API Gateway call an AppSync endpoint wherein the flexbile schema can be enforced and all Integration Responses are just passthroughs in proper JSON -- requires maintaining an AppSync endpoint and adds a bit of turnaround time to all calls

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to call lambda?

Comment: @JasonWadsworth sure. I’m attempting to create a developer API for my startup with a paywall for volume users and AppSync doesn’t make that easy to do (extra Lambda layer with auth considerations). I figured I’d use API Gateway and directly connect to our DynamoDB table using it as the gateway service. The returns are variably nested in some cases though so the DynamoDB integration is too limited (hence the `util` reference). If I can’t use the integration service I’d have to just use a Lambda integration, which to me, makes the whole DynamoDB integration here kind of pointless.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth honestly though, I could just be highly over complicating all of this

Comment: Personally I find the direct integrations with DynamoDB to be a little odd. It could be useful to do a quick POC, and I suppose it's okay for simple cases, but I don't see it being useful beyond that.

Comment: Same. I tend to just do everything in Lambda because of it. I was sort of hoping this time it might not be necessary. Just seemed more convenient, at first. I’ll probably end up doing it with Lambda here too. Thanks for the input though!